# React JS: calling event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I have started working in React recently. I noticed one behaviour like when I am trying to call my event handle with the same component like this
onClick={someEventHandler} it is triggering but when I try to do the same same like this onClick={()=> someEventHandler} it doesn't work.

I noticed that when I need to pass any arguments and calling the function like onClick={()=>someEventHandler(id)} it is working fine.

can some one explain me the logic/theory behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onClick event handler needs a function to be passed to it. Whenn the event is triggered, it calls the handler function passed to it.

In the first case it works because you pass `someEventHandler` to onClick which is invoked when event is fired. An invocation to the function is like `someEventHandler()`

Now in the second case,

```
onClick={()=>someEventHandler}
```

the function passed to onClick is `()=>someEventHandler` which can be elaborated further as `()=> { return someEventHandler; }`

Now if you notice above you are returning a function from the onClick event handler. The returned function is now never invoked and hence you see the above behavior

It works in the last case like `onClick={()=>someEventHandler(id)}`, because when the event handler is invoked, it invoked someEventHandler with id too.

However you do not need to pass id to invoke it, you can simply use it like `onClick={()=>someEventHandler()}` and it work, provided you don't need id as a parameter in someEventHandler.

Another thing to note when you are using function like `onClick={()=>someEventHandler()}` instead of `onClick={someEventHandler}` is that your `someEventHandler` will not be invoked with any arguments. If you want the event to be passed as argument to someEventHandler, you need tto explicitly pass it like

```
onClick={(e)=>someEventHandler(e)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation Shubham.

Answer (score 0):

`onClick={someEventHandler}` will trigger the handler as soon as your component gets loaded/rendered on the screen but by adding an arrow function before the handler like this -  `onClick={()=> someEventHandler}` will make sure not to trigger the component before you click on it

Comment: I think you misunderstood the issue. `onClick={someEventHandler}` works, but `onClick={()=> someEventHandler}` doesn't. The first one *won't trigger* the handler. It simply passes the handler to `onClick`. You are confusing this with `onClick={someEventHandler()}` which would indeed be incorrect.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, you are right. I was working with these exact things and thought that I've seen those above mentioned functions with parenthesis.